# Welcome User vs. Username

Tags: html, mysql, cookies

How would I go about making this code below, display a user's "Username" instead of saying "Welcome, User"?

Note, I have the cookie files, connected already to MySQL and I am just wondering how I would go about making it connect to that `<div>`.

```
 <body>
      <div id="container" style="width:400px;">
                  <div id="logged_bar">Welcome, User<span class='logout'><a href='?logout=1'>Logout</a></span></div>


<table id="creator" border="1" bgcolor="#FF0000" cellpadding="5" align="center" width="100%" style="text-align:center; border-color:#000; margin-top:10px; border-collapse:collapse;">
```

Comment: What technology are you using? "connect to that div" isn't really a description of what you are trying to do. Use php or JavaScript to read your cookie and write the result to the div. This has nothing to do with html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using php.

```
      <div id="logged_bar">Welcome, <? $_COOKIE["your_cookie_name_here"] ?>
<span class='logout'>...
```

Comment: But it was just a good guess, you need to put more details for your questions to get more useful answers. Keep in mind for next time :)

Comment: Granted, Thank you very much, Also thank you for the quick replys.

Comment: @Gavin : If it's the correct answer, please mark it as accepted with check mark beside Kuzgun answer.